# Can you use .so libs from one application in other application?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, lib

If there is an application that has a .so lib. say "example.so", that has a function like `Java_com_domain_demo_exampleFuntion`, can you call it from your application which has a different application id?

If the new application ID is `com.otherdomain.demo2` then there is an error like

> No implementation found for void Java_com_otherdomain_demo2_exampleFuntion()

Answer (score 1):

There is another means of achieving this if you cannot rename your application: write a small `.so` file that links with `example.so` and that calls JNI's `registerNatives` in its `JNI_OnLoad` function:

The following example is adapted from the [Android JNI documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries):

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    // Find your class. JNI_OnLoad is called from the correct class loader context for this to work.
    jclass c = env->FindClass("com/markov/App/MyClass");
    if (c == nullptr) return JNI_ERR;

    // Register your class' native methods.
    static const JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
        {"myExampleFunction", "()V", reinterpret_cast(Java_com_domain_demo_exampleFuntion)},
    };
    int rc = env->RegisterNatives(c, methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(JNINativeMethod));
    if (rc != JNI_OK) return rc;

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

This example binds `Java_com_domain_demo_exampleFuntion` to `com.markov.App.MyClass#myExampleFunction`.
You can add more functions to the `methods` array, of course.

Note that the behavior of the functions you copy may depend on certain fields of the class you bind it to. If those fields are not present on your `com.markov.App.MyClass` class, the JNI invocation will fail or crash. For example, many Java wrappers use `long` fields to store pointers to C memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to create special module(same package name) which It named like Java_com_domain_demo_exampleFuntion(). And you using this module another app. But, you can't use *.so file other app with different package name.